# Should I create Cucumber features for API gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, bdd

I gonna create gem that holds the business logic of the [rubywarrior](https://github.com/ryanb/ruby-warrior) gem and make it to use that API gem for logic, and be used only for terminal command for playing the game. Okay so should I write features for that future gem or specs are enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specs seem like they would have a better value for the time invested than cucumber.

Cucumber provides the advantage of human readable specs for non-technical stakeholders, but if you're shipping a gem that may not be worth much.

I vote for rspec functional tests.